# Design Schema advice for large array MongoDB - Mongoose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, nosql

I have a map of polygons in Json format. This haves all the polygons [lat,long] coordinates. 
Each polygon have an index ID and will be validate by users by assigning color red, green, blue.
Because many people will validate at the same time, I don't know what design would be the best to accomplished this. We want to make it fast because there w

My schema right now is storing such as

data: [{'1': 'r'}, {'2': 'g'}] and so on. But there would be more than 5000 polygons.

On top of that there would be different maps too.

Should I have my maps as 1 document, with ref to [users]. Or have an array of validation result within Users document?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think you should choose your first option. Actually if you have a big array and the array may increase in the future, you should use separated collection instead of the array for performance your app.
If you have to use a big embedded array you can try to create an index for your array.

There is a useful article from Asya Kamsky relevant this issue. You can reach [from here](http://askasya.com/post/largeembeddedarrays).

> There is one more thing that you can do that will completely kill your
>   application's performance and that's to index this ever-increasing
>   array. What that means is that every single time the document with
>   this array is relocated, the number of index entries that need to be
>   updated is directly proportional to the number of indexed values in
>   that document, and the bigger the array, the larger that number will
>   be.